# How do I fetch additional history in a git-svn clone?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

I've already done `git svn clone` to create a repo. It has one year of history. I want to extend how far back my history goes. How can I do that?

I tried using fetch with my start revision, but it did nothing and had no output:

```
git svn fetch -r 100000
```

I have existing branches with work that's not yet dcommitted to svn, so I don't want to create a new clone.